# Display HTML Tags and Content in label Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I am making a blog, using Apache Wicket. For the Rich text editor, I am using stackoverflow markdown fork I got from Github. It stores the HTML in the database. When I retrieve the content and display it in a label, I am facing a problem.

The problem is that the users may contain both content and code, So on retrieving the content from the database I use `label.setEscapeModelStrings(false);` on my Label so as to preserve the formatting. But if the post contains HTML in the `pre` tag, that is also parsed and rendered.

I want that the HTML in the `pre` tag may not be rendered and shown as it is.

The problem only comes when the user post contains some HTML code. Any solution, server-side or client-side?

Thanks

**Update** 
May be I can parse the content with Jsoup and escape the content inside `pre`.
Example would be:-
 
`content.replaceAll(">","&gt;");`

Comment: I think you'll have to escape html in pre tags by hand (i.e. javascript before sending it to your server)...

Comment: @Nicktar please see updated question, what do you think about this approach?
I am not really very comforatble with Javascript

Comment: With the typo fixed this looks workable but I'd suggest to use the Wicket built-in methods to actually escape these parts. The Wicket method to do so is org.apache.wicket.util.string.Strings.escapeMarkup(CharSequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially followed @Nicktar's suggestion of escaping the string before storing to database,
 
But since I am not very good @ Javascript I chose to use Jsoup to parse the string and escape content in the `pre` tag. Here is the code :-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(labelText); //labelText comes from input
    Elements titleElements = doc.getElementsByTag("pre");
    for (Element pre : titleElements) {
        String content = pre.html().replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
        String content2 = content.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
        pre.html(content2);
    }

//Save to db..
```

And it works.